# Powershell: Start-Process with a file variable

Tags: powershell

c:\test.ps1 exists and is an empty file.

```
Start-Process -filepath powershell -argumentlist { -noexit -file "c:\test.ps1" }
```

opens a new powershell window and keeps it open (which is what I want).

```
$a = "c:\test.ps1"
Start-Process -filepath powershell -argumentlist { -noexit -file "$a" }
```

briefly flashes a new Powershell window and then closes it immediately.
I wonder why?

Comment: Change `{ -noexit -file "$a" }` to `'-noexit','-file',$a`

Comment: Good point re script blocks, @MathiasR.Jessen, but I suggest always recommending a _single_ string that encodes all arguments, for the reasons stated in my answer. For instance - as unfortunate as that is - if `$a` happens to contain a path _with spaces_, `-ArgumentList '-noexit', '-file', $a` _fails_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

To pass pass-through arguments to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter:

- DO NOT use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`).
- DO use a single, [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`):

```sh
$a = "c:\test.ps1"
Start-Process powershell "-noexit -file `"$a`""
```

<sup>Note: Parameter names `-FilePath` and `-ArgumentList` are *positionally implied* in this command; that is, the command is equivalent to `` Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -file `"$a`"" ``</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s **`-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter is `[string[]]` typed, i.e. it expects an array of *string* arguments** to pass to the external program being launched - given that strings are the only supported data type when passing arguments to *external programs*.

- Note: While passing pass-through arguments *individually*, as the elements of an *array*, to `-ArgumentList` (`-ArgumentList '-noexit', '-file', $a`) is *conceptually* the best approach, it is unfortunately ill-advised due to a long-standing bug in `Start-Process`, still present as of this writing (v7.2)  - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).
  For now, using a *single* string comprising *all* arguments, each enclosed in *embedded* `"..."` quoting if necessary (as shown above), is the only robust approach.
  As discussed in the linked GitHub issue, an `-ArgumentArray` parameter that supports robust array-based argument passing may be introduced in the future.

When you pass a *script block* (`{ ... }`), it is *stringified* (its `.ToString()` method is implicitly called, and a script block's stringification is its *verbatim contents* (excluding the enclosing `{` and `}`), which means that *no* expansion (string interpolation) takes place;
try `{ $HOME }.ToString()`, for instance.

- Note: You *can* use script blocks when you invoke `powershell.exe` *directly*, synchronously (rather than via `Start-Process`), but only *from PowerShell*, and such script blocks are executed by the *callee*, and therefore also do *not* see the caller's variables; you can, however, pass arguments to them; e.g.:
  `powershell { "args passed: $args" } -args 1, 2`